# How to wrap text around an image in Wagtail

Tags: wagtail

The Wagtail documentation on [Inserting images and videos in a page](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/editor_manual/new_pages/inserting_images.html) explicitly states

> Half-width left/right aligned: Inserts the image at half the width of the text area. If inserted in a block of text, the text will wrap around the image

How does one implement this?

I have created a page with an Rich Text block and inserted an image in the text (left aligned)

[image]

When I publish the page it is not wrapped
[image]

What can I do to fix this in Wagtail without the need for an html/css solution?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid an html/css solution?

Comment: Are you implying that Wagtail does NOT do the wrap as suggested by the docs? I'm not sure that I would know how to tell where in the page the user wanted the image to appear

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a CSS rule such as `img.left {float: left}`. As per the developer docs on [images embedded in rich text](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/images.html#images-embedded-in-rich-text):

> The CSS classes added to images do not come with any accompanying stylesheets, or inline styles. e.g. the left class will do nothing, by default. The developer is expected to add these classes to their front end CSS files, to define exactly what they want left, right or full-width to mean.

In general, Wagtail leaves front-end styling up to the developer. This detail isn't covered in the page of documentation you looked at because that's part of the editor's manual, intended to be given to non-technical users after the development side is complete.

Comment: You have advanced my knowledge and now I can add my own rtf image formats (e.g. centre an image on the page). However when I try to use my float format and try to place an image in a paragraph of text the editor adds paragraph tags before and after the image and so  i still end up with the output as shown in my question. No text wrapping