# How to wrap text around an image in Wagtail using latest version

Tags: wagtail

I want to be able to put images into my text, with the text wrapping to the left or right of the image, but when I edit I only get the + sign to the left of the bar when I start a new paragraph.

There is a similar question here: [How to wrap text around an image in Wagtail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65155879/how-to-wrap-text-around-an-image-in-wagtail)

However the answer of applying a CSS style does not work as you have

> `<p>text</p><image><p>more text</p>`

Any idea how to add an image into text? Latest Wagtail version.

Tried to add an image to the left or right of some text. It appears on its own line with one paragraph of text above it and another underneath it. Tried using the CSS solution, does not work.

Comment: SOLVED: Don't use Firefox. It was completely ignoring updates in the CSS stylesheet despite refreshing the page and the .css tab. Using Chromium solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wrap text around an image, the easiest option is to [add "image"  to your allowed editor options](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#limiting-features-in-a-rich-text-field). Wagtail's image inserter comes with 3 formats, full width, left, and right. But it is up to you to add the CSS required for doing the alignment - just as was answered in the SO post you linked to above. If you want to create different formats, you can [customize the list of options using the instructions in this docs](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#image-formats-in-the-rich-text-editor).

Comment: No this does not work. "image" is in my allowed editor options. It does not appear when editing a paragraph. Therefore I cannot add an image to the paragraph. No I cannot add CSS to do the alignment. As I say in the text, the paragraph is enclosed in open and close paragraph tags. Then the image comes next. Then the next paragraph appears enclosed in open and closed paragraph tags. How do I make the image 'magically' jump within the p and slash p of the paragraph?

Comment: Thanks cnk. The CSS was working but not showing up due to Firefox refusing to update. As mentioned above, switching to Chromium worked.